# ActiveMQ how to send async message inside method annotated with JmsListener

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

My goal is simple I have to send notification(about in progress state) instantly after reciving message from JmsListener.

What I did so far is setting async send in yml

```
broker-url: tcp://localhost:61616?jms.useAsyncSend=true
```

and nothing happend, obviously it doesnt work like that

My problem is that all messages are being sent after message is already processed. It looks like sync mode.

My simplified code looks like this

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${messagesQueue}")
public void handleMessage(Message message){
   jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("statusQueue", Status.IN_PROGRESS);
   //... processing stuff
   //... onSuccess
   jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("statusQueue", Status.OK);

   //... onFailure
   jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("statusQueue", Status.ERROR);

}
```

I use spring boot with fully automated config

Any advice is welcome! What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found workaround by passing initial in progress message to another thread.

```
new Thread(() -> {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("statusQueue", Status.IN_PROGRESS);
}).start();
```

Looks ugly and I don't think its final solution but it may help someone else.